# RIA: how to get functionality, not a data

Tags: .net, ria

On the server side I have the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return string.Concat(FirstName, " ", SecondName); } }
}
```

The problem is that each field is calculated and transferred to the client (to the Silvelight application), for example 'FullName' property:

```
    [DataMember()]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fullName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._fullName != value))
            {
                this.ValidateProperty("FullName", value);
                this.OnFullNameChanging(value);
                this._fullName = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
                this.OnFullNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of data transferring (that is traffic consuming, in some cases it introduces significant overhead). I would like to have a calculation on the client side (silverlight aplpication).

Is this possible without manual duplication of the property implementation?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming this is for a web form or something, can't you do validation using AJAX or JavaScript?

Comment: I am sorry, ... what can I do with validation? The purpose of the functionality copying is to calculate and display FullName as "Alex Sereda" on the client side in case when we have FirstName="Alex" and SecondName="Sereda" without passing value of the FullName property.

Answer (score 0):

Move the calculated properties to a different file as a partial class and utilize teh "Shared" naming convetion (MyFileName.Shared.cs). Example:

```
//Employee.cs
public partial class Employee
{
   [Key]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//Employee.Shared.cs
public partial class Employee
{
    public string LastNameFirst
    {
      get { return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName); }
    }
}
```

The code in the Shared file will show up on the client side.